# Running git from Windows Cmd line: Where are key files?

Tags: git, ssh, msysgit

So I've installed msysgit, and run git successfuly from the bash shell.

From within the bash shell, I've created keys with `ssh-keygen` - everything works fine.
Key files are in my `%userprofile%\.ssh` folder (from the bash shell, it is: `~/.ssh`).
I'm able to connect to my server (unfuddle in my case).

Next, I do want to be able to run git from the Windows Cmd shell.
Adding `c:\msysgit\bin` and `c:\msysgit\mingw\bin` to the search path.
Git is working *locally* just fine: branch, merge, add, commit, checkout, ... working well.

However, trying to work with the server fails, with: '`Permission denied (publickey).`'
It looks like git, when executed from command line looks at a different location trying to allocated the key files, or another reason causing it to fail.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

To get the mysysgit command line to find the .ssh keys you'll need to have `%HOME%` point to the directory containing the .ssh folder

Often you can just do

```
set HOME=%USERPROFILE%
```

Comment: Thank you JaredPar and VonC. Your suggestion has worked. +1 to both.

Comment: I'm getting the same error.  I have set %HOME% in this way ... still no joy.   Any other suggestions?   What might I be missing?

Comment: I've been looking everywhere for this answer... Thanks @JaredPar

Comment: I have been fighting with this for an hour and this is the answer that finally worked.

Answer (score 15):

From a Windows DOS file, you need to define a `%HOME%` environment variable.

`HOME` doesn't exist in a DOS session by default.
You can set it to `%userprofile%`, since this is already your current setting.
You also can add it to your user environment variables, in order for any DOS session to get it.

Comment: Worked to set the User Environment Variable, thanks for this lifesaver!