# Embed Git bash in PyCharm as external tool and work with it in PyCharm window (windows xp)

Tags: git, intellij-idea, pycharm, windows-xp, git-bash

I added cmd as external tool in PyCharm, and it works nicely in PyCharm console (View -> Run). [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17302977/how-to-launch-git-bash-from-dos-command-line)
is described how to launch Git bash from cmd. It opens in separate window, but I want it to be in the same PyCharm window, so I can type commands without pressing the CTRL+TAB.

I suppose there should be other way, more straight-forward, but I dont see it.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Configure the Terminal to use `bash.exe` or `sh.exe` from Git installation like this:

[image: sh.exe]

`"c:\Program Files\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login`

Use `Tools` | `Open Terminal...` (or click on the Terminal tool window) then run your git command in the Terminal tool window.

Comment: HOW? Terminal looks like blank space, I cant type in it. Its just useless brick. I also got some Version Control Console, its only displays something useless and irrelevant, but it also a brick without input.

Comment: Commands can be typed in the Terminal: http://img36.imageshack.us/img36/2138/3sx0.png.

Comment: What OS version do you use? Can you share [idea.log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23352446)? Please note that Terminal is currently not compatible with Windows XP.

Comment: Worked without --login

Comment: --login seems to give me color output.

Comment: What does --login do?

Comment: @Andromeda See https://linux.die.net/man/1/sh: "When bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a non-interactive shell with the --login option, it first reads and executes commands from the file /etc/profile, if that file exists. After reading that file, it looks for ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile, in that order, and reads and executes commands from the first one that exists and is readable."

Answer (score 56):

File -> settings -> terminal -> shell path

Paste this if you have a 32-bit installation of Git:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login
```

Or this for 64-bit installation:

```
"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login
```

The quotes are important: if you don't specify them you'll get an error because the path contains spaces.

If you encounter `java.io.IOException: Couldn't create PTY`, check that:

1. There is an istallation of git in the specified path.
2. You have used quotes around the path.

Comment: Please make sure to use quotes around the path, it has spaces. If you don't put the spaces you'll get java.io.IOException: Couldn't create PTY

Comment: THANK YOU! Couldn't figure out the --login!

Comment: For me it was in location: `C:\Users\<USERNAME>\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\bin\sh.exe`

Answer (score -1):

You must add to PATH variable

```
;C:\Program Files\Git\bin
```

And open terminal in idea.