# Bash commands missing (bash: command not found) after manually activating virtual environment in PyCharm Git-Bash console on Windows

Tags: pycharm, git-bash, python-venv

After embedding Git-Bash in PyCharm (2019.1.3 CE) on Windows following [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20573213/embed-git-bash-in-pycharm-as-external-tool-and-work-with-it-in-pycharm-window-w) (or [this one](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000716044/comments/115000612190)) I've encountered a following problem using virtual environment (created with stdlib [`venv` package](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html)):

- PyCharm fails to automatically activate virtual environment.
- After manual activation (which can be done following [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10450992/can-not-activate-a-virtualenv-in-git-bash-mingw32-for-windows)) some Bash commands (like `git`/`rm`) went missing:

  ```
  $ git status
  On branch ...
  Your branch is up to date with '.../...'.

  nothing to commit, working tree clean

  $ . venv/Scripts/activate

  (venv) $ git status
  bash: git: command not found
  ```

Even after deactivation

```
(venv) $ deactivate

$ git status
bash: git: command not found
```

they are not accessible.

Answer (score 4):

As a workaround I've ended up disabling option "Activate virtualenv" in *File* -> *Settings* -> *Tools* -> *Terminal* menu:

[image: Settings]

and after saving changes & reopening terminal it seems to work

```
$ . venv/Scripts/activate

(venv) $ git status
On branch ...
Your branch is up to date with '.../...'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```