# Execute Git Bash with parameters, from Windows PowerShell/Batch File

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, git-bash

I have a command that I need to execute from `Git Bash` in `Administrator` mode.

Is there a way I could create a `Windows Batch` file or `PowerShell` to do these steps?

At the moment I'm doing the following:

1. In the Windows Explorer GUI, right click on Git Bash, and select, 'Run as administrator'.
2. Type the command `kubectl port-forward svc/camunda-operate 8081:80 -n camunda` and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

I've found, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17302977), a way to launch `Git Bash` from `cmd.exe`, but I was unable to get it running elevated, and pass the command to `Git Bash`.

Comment: something like 

   `"%PROGRAMFILES%\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i -c "kubectl port-forward svc/camunda-operate 8081:80 -n camunda"` 
 Probably wrap that up in a runas /user:admin command.

Comment: Thanks Alex, but the bash did not open. The kubectl command ran in the CMD itself.

Comment: I thought that was the desired effect. To get Bash to run in CMD and execute your command with a script.  Was there an error message?

Comment: There was no error on the window.. I will try to use it for a some time and see if it is doing the same as using the Git Bash

Comment: kubectl and bash scripts used work very nicely WSL2. If possible I would move the work with kubectl to WSL2 and use bash there, instead of using Git bash.

Answer (score 0):

From PowerShell:

```bash
Start-Process -Verb RunAs "$env:ProgramFiles\Git\git-bash.exe" '-c "kubectl port-forward svc/camunda-operate 8081:80 -n camunda"'
```

- This launches an *elevated* Git Bash session, invariably in a *new window*.
- Note that the new window closes automatically when the launched `kubectl` command terminates.